# System.ArgumentNullException in System.ni.dll - Xamarin IIF like VB.net

Tags: c#, xamarin, null

**Answering my own question as I couldn't find a solution to this problem online.**

---

I get this error when running a Xamarin app using VS2013:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in
>   System.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

It occurs on this line:

WinDevice:

```
LoadApplication(new App());
```

iOS:

```
UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
```

Android:

```
LoadApplication(new App());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure all the resources are available, in my case an image was missing:

```
Icon = Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS ? "slideout.png" : null;
```

**I thought the Image resource wasn't necessary because I was not targeting the iOS platform.**

*Its reminiscent of VB.Net's IIF where both sides are evaluated (ie the If statement is not short-circuited).*